# Share connections between postgresql and PDO (psql)

Tags: postgresql, pdo

Question is simple, is it possible to share opened connection between the one created with `pg_connect` and the one created with new `PDO("pgsql"...)` or vice versa?

Comment: For what purpose? You want to look at connection pooling: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Replication,_Clustering,_and_Connection_Pooling

Comment: @Nicarus The reason is simple, one of our applications has used from historical reasons `pg_connect`ion - as most of them by that time - but, after some time we started using `illuminate/database` with eloquent models and we had to initiate a new type of connection, `PDO` connection to the same db - and until the time the whole application is refactored, it would be better if the connection could be shared :)

Answer (score 2):

The answer is simple. It's impossible.